# What is mean by Developing a model to predict the target variable minimizing 'Root Mean Squared Error' function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So, it's a regression problem and I have to predict the values of a variable. What I don't understand is that what exactly it means when it says, "predict the column 'abc' minimizing 'rmse' loss function"?

I have created a Linear Regression model and I got the score of 99.8. Is it really that simple or is there something that I'm missing?

Does it mean anything else than just showing the root mean square error after I get the predicted variable?

When I use Linear Regression, I get RMSE of 2.467. And when I use Random Forest, I get RMSE of 1.336.

Is my model good or do I need to do something else to 'minimize the RMSE function'?

P.S - I'm using python to create the model by using the `sklearn` library.

Comment: “ I have created a Linear Regression model and I got an accuracy of more than 99%.” —- how do you measure an accuracy for a regression model?

Comment: I'd recommend you to read first some basics of Machine Learning before approaching ML problems. For instance, you're talking about regression problem and says that you've got accuracy 99%. But accuracy is defined only for classification problems. Arguing whether a model is good also makes sense only in a context.

Comment: I used the score function on the Linear regression instance.

Comment: @MikhailBerlinkov I should've said I got the score of 99, not the accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have better luck in cross validation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

However regarding the programming part, `MSE` or `RMSE` is a measure of distance between the predicted values and the real values. If you are using an algorithm to predict quantities, you might want to know how off you were in your prediction in contrast to the real values.

The main goal is to minimize this distance, that is, make your model predict values (y-hat) that match or are really close to the real ones (y) by adjusting weights and parameters mostly. The best you can do to improve (lower) the `RMSE` is hyperparameter tuning, this means finding the optimal `max_depth`, `n_features`, `min_sample_weight` and other parameters for your `RandomForrestRegressor`, this is once you've decided to stick with a certain Regression model (`RandomForrest` seems better than `Linear Regression` in this case).

Finally, a certain value of `RMSE` cannot be arbitrarily considered as good or bad. Say you are predicting weights. If you are working with elephants, a `RMSE` of **1** might be great if it's **1 milligram**, it might be awful if it's **1 ton**.

This is the most I can share with you about `RMSE` that fits the StackOverflow scope, as I mentioned before, for in-depth explanation and better answers, you should try the link above.

Comment: I see. So, I just use the `RandomizedSearchCV` and define a parameter grid and then create the model. Thank you. I really appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Certainly, `RandomizedSearchCV` is a powerful way to tune some hyperparameters. Furthermore try feature augmentation, and some other techniques that are not proper of the model, but can do wonders.

Comment: Feel free to leave a comment if there's any more I can help you with, or accept my answer if it helped you solve the problem :)

Comment: I used the `RandomizedSearchCV` and build the model using the best estimators. But somehow RMSE is 4.41 compared to previous 1.33. Any Idea why that is?

Comment: That's strange, you mean the .best_params_ performs worse than the default settings? I assume you are working with the same data

Comment: Yes the .best_params_. And yes, ofcourse I used that on the same data.

Comment: I tried tweaking the param_grid a little bit but could only able to get it down to 2.9. Now I'm thinking about leaving it on default.

Comment: Just to compare I made a Linear Regression model using OLS method and optimized it using Backward Elimination method. This model got the Adj. R-squared of 0.998 and the RMSE of 2.463. So, I guess default Random Forest Regressor is still the better choice since it got the RMSE of 1.33? What do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207025/discussion-between-celius-stingher-and-ab1004).